# Unable to send mail in Silverlight

Tags: email, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I wrote a WCF service for sending mail in Silverlight:

```
using System.Web.Mail;

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = emailFrom;
msg.To = emailTo;
msg.Subject = msgSubject;
msg.Body = msgBody;
msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

SmtpMail.Send(msg);
success = true;
```

This works fine in localhost, but when I host it in IIS, it doesn't show any error, but no mail has been received. What may be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like server configuration issue, not programming related

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the smtpserver property for the smtpmail class before you call the send method.

Comment: You can specify which is the mail server to use for send, through the SmtpMail.SmtpServer property. Check the Remarks section from his specification [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail.aspx). Commonly in production servers, you must specify this kind of information and a valid user credentials to be authorized for send email in this case i recommend you to use the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient. Check this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/QuickEmailSend.aspx?msg=3436378&display=Mobile) for ilustration.

Comment: No.. Still i am struggling..!  I think it might be a configuration issue..? Any idea abt that...?

Comment: Hi elvin.., Thanks for your response.. After a long struggle, i got it. This has been fixed after referring the webservice url running in IIS at endpoint address of ServicesReferences.ClientConfig file. Now i am very happy.. Once again, Great thanks for all of your response